# Data import from mysql to solr?

Tags: mysql, solr

Sorry but I am new in solr but I am stuck in this.

**First what I am doing:** I have use Tomcat server to install my solr.

**What I want to do:** I want to import mysql data to solr.

I have been searching for hours but could not find a proper solution to it have seen many question but to nearest to it was this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809106/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-to-solr). but it was no help cause it have a different error.

**This is my command:**

```
 http://localhost:8080/solr/db/dataimport?command=full-import
```

**This is my error:**

```
Error:HTTP Status 404 - /solr/db/dataimport

type: Status report

message: /solr/db/dataimport

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Sorry I am new to solr any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have a collection named db? You can see this in the collection list in the admin interface. (`/admin`)

Answer (score 0):

This line is from the example that ships with Solr. If you just found it on the internet, see the **README.txt** file in the *example/example-DIH* directory of the distribution.

If you are trying to configure your own collection, you need to replace the **db** part with your collection name and you need to configure DIH in solrconfig.xml (libraries and end-point) and you need to configure the import definition to use your own database.