# How do I import a mySQL database table into Solr 6?

Tags: mysql, solr, solr6

I am trying to import a simple mySQL table into Solr and keep failing.
Having ploughed through:

- https://gist.github.com/maxivak/3e3ee1fca32f3949f052
- https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler
- [How to import data from mysql to solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809106/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-to-solr)

and half a dozen other posts that are related to Solr4, I am in desperate need of some community help.

I need specific instructions for Solr 6, it's installed on RedHat to connect to a mySQL DB. Thanks a lot.

Comment: where is it failing..? could your share the error?

Comment: I started with a clean VM each time, so I cannot give you logs. The last version was when I got no error message, it just simply did not execute the import, or rather it did, it just had nothing to update... For now, I'd rather not do more troubleshooting but start with a clean config for Solr6.

Comment: for me everything works fine ...I am using solr 6.2 dataimporthandler along with tika integration...

Comment: Magic. Can you point me in the direction of the exact steps you followed? I'd really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Its bit lengthy so adding in the answer block...

Comment: Did the steps helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the steps below..

1. Install Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 for Solr 6.1
2. Set Java home "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101/"
3. Download solr 6.1 "solr-6.1.0.tgz" from http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/6.1.0/
4. Extract tgz file using "tar zxf solr-6.1.0.tgz".
5. Open the port 8983 as to communicate with solr.
6. Go to the path ../solr-6.1.0/ and start the server with "bin/solr start"
7. Create a config folder named myConfig under configsets directory , move the conf folder into it. Add the data-config.xml into "/myConfig/conf".

Modified the schema.xml under the folder "/myConfig/conf" and add the data-config.xml.

add teh entry in solconfig.xml

data-config.xml

2. Fire the url to create the core.

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=mycore&instanceDir=my_instance&configSet=myConfig

5. Add the jars "solr-dataimporthandler-6.1.0.jar", "solr-dataimporthandler-extras-6.1.0.jar" to path "/home/abhijit/Downloads/solr-6.1.0/server/lib".
6. Add the "solr-core-6.1.0.jar" jar to the path "/home/abhijit/Downloads/solr-6.1.0/server/lib".
7. Add the "solr-solrj-6.1.0.jar" jar to the path "/home/abhijit/Downloads/solr-6.1.0/server/lib".
8. If you do the above steps you will ge the error like :

   "Error Instantiating requestHandler, org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler"
   This problem occurred because dataimporthandler and requesthandler are loaded by two different class loaders. To solve it, ensure that solr loads its jars only from the same class loader.

   Option to steps 5,6,7 create a folder lib inside the solr folder at path "/home/abhijit/Downloads/solr-6.1.0/server/solr"
   and add the entry of the same to solrConfig.xml as "".
   Comment the other lib entries from solrConfig.xml
   the jars "solr-dataimporthandler-6.1.0.jar", "solr-dataimporthandler-extras-6.1.0.jar" to path "/home/abhijit/Downloads/solr-6.1.0/server/solr/lib".
9. Commented the updateRequestProcessorChain in solrConfig.xml.
10. Command for full import

http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true

if you have any params to pass on then do something like this

http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true&cabinetId=5654174